# Simultaneous update of various columns in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

While updating my table only first value retrieved from `path_name` gets inserted into every cell which is not expected.

Current result:

```
path_bak           file_exists  file_is_a_dir   parent_dir_exists
folder/file_1.BAK  1            0               1
folder/file_1.BAK  0            0               1
```

Expected result, once `FETCH` retreives new value of `path` it should get inserted into `path_bak`.

```
path_bak           file_exists  file_is_a_dir   parent_dir_exists
folder/file_1.BAK  1            0               1
folder/file_2.BAK  0            0               1
```

Current code snippet causing issues:

```
DECLARE @diff_path NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @tableVar TABLE (path_bak NVARCHAR(MAX), file_exists INT, file_is_a_dir INT, parent_dir_exists INT)
 
DECLARE path_name CURSOR FOR
       SELECT msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.physical_device_name
                     --MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date) AS last_db_backup_date 
       FROM msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily  
       INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset ON msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.media_set_id = msdb.dbo.backupset.media_set_id  
                                  
       WHERE msdb..backupset.type = 'I' 
       AND msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name = 'db_name'
                  
       GROUP BY msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.physical_device_name
       ORDER BY MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date) DESC;
 
OPEN path_name;  
  
--Perform the first fetch.  
FETCH NEXT FROM path_name INTO @diff_path; 
 
--Check @@FETCH_STATUS to see if there are any more rows to fetch.  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
   --This is executed as long as the previous fetch succeeds.  
   SET @sql = 'EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist ''' + @diff_path + ''''
   INSERT INTO @tableVar(file_exists, file_is_a_dir, parent_dir_exists) EXEC sp_executesql @sql 
   UPDATE @tableVar SET path_bak = @diff_path
 
   FETCH NEXT FROM path_name INTO @diff_path;  
END  
 
 
--test results
SELECT * FROM @tableVar
 
CLOSE path_name;  
DEALLOCATE path_name;  
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `update` is updating all rows.  You need a `WHERE` clause to identify the most recent row . . . but that is a little tricky with your current structure.

My recommendation is to load the data into a temporary table and then load into the final table:

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist ''' + @diff_path + '''';

    DECLARE @temp TABLE (file_exists int, file_is_a_dir int, parent_dir_exists int);

    DELETE FROM @temp;

    INSERT INTO @temp (file_exists, file_is_a_dir, parent_dir_exists)
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

    INSERT INTO @tableVar (path_bak, file_exists, file_is_a_dir, parent_dir_exists)
        SELECT @diff_path, file_exists, file_is_a_dir, parent_dir_exists
        FROM @temp;

    FETCH NEXT FROM path_name INTO @diff_path
END;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7f91b7e06086fd4e6dd9a5f5ddc84b35) is a db<>fiddle with a mockup of the logic.

Comment: I got and error: `OUTPUT cannot be used in INSERT...EXEC statement`

Comment: @marcin2x4 . . . Funny, as I was writing the answer, I was thinking "I don't think I've every use `OUTPUT` with `INSERT . . . EXEC, but it *must* work."  Ha ha.  An alternative solution is to use a temporary table to load the data and then insert into the final table.  I changed the answer.

Comment: we're getting closer. I fixed the line `DECLARE @temp TABLE (file_exists int, file_is_a_dir int, parent_dir_exists int);` Now it seems we get cartesian product combo ;)

Comment: @marcin2x4 . . . I didn't realize that `@temp` is not re-initialized during each loop iteration.  The solution is just to delete everything on each iteration.